# Adding date in variable name in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a column with name total transaction. I want to add a date 4 days back from now in its name .

For example if today is 20161220 so I want my variable to be renamed as **total_transaction_20161216**.

Please suggest me a way out of my problem.

Comment: In general purpose while working in SAS i use intnx(date, today(), -4) for getting a date 4 days back from now, but i do not know how to add it in variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a macro variable that stores the required date format and then use that in a `rename` statement within `proc datasets`.

```
%let datevar = %sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-4),yymmddn8.);

%put &=datevar.;

data have;
total_transaction=1;
run;

proc datasets lib=work nolist nodetails;
modify have;
rename total_transaction = total_transaction_&datevar.;
quit;
```